# serial port taking a huge amount of time to reopen itself after closing by catching an exception

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, idisposable, ui-thread, comobject

I am trying to catch a time-out exception by sending data through serial port like this,

```
    ReadTimeout = 1000     '// 1000 milliseconds = 1 seconds
    WriteTimeout = 1000    '// 1000 milliseconds = 1 seconds

    Try
        If COMPort.IsOpen Then
            COMPort.Write(dataToSend)
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
            COMPort.DiscardInBuffer()
            COMPort.DiscardOutBuffer()

            Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf ClosePort)
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            t.Start()
    End Try

Private Sub ClosePort()
    If COMPort.IsOpen Then
        COMPort.DiscardInBuffer()
        COMPort.DiscardOutBuffer()

        Try
            COMPort.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox(ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

By catching the time out exception I am able to close the port immediately but when I reopen the serialPort again I have to wait around 1-2 minutes before the port reopens itself. Because, I am new newbie I read the documents and find out that serialPort it an unmanaged resource therefore it is not directly under the control of garbage collector.

I found an API called ReleaseCOMObject(o as Object) as Integer. I tried to use this API like that,

```
    Dim WithEvents COMPort As New SerialPort

Private Sub ReleaseCOMObject(obj As Object)
    Dim countDown As Int32
    countDown = 1

    While (countDown > 0)
        countDown = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj)
    End While

End Sub

Private Sub ClosePort()
    If COMPort.IsOpen Then
        COMPort.DiscardInBuffer()
        COMPort.DiscardOutBuffer()

        Try
            ReleaseCOMObject(COMPort)
            COMPort.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            MsgBox(ex.StackTrace)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

The API accepts this COMPort as SerialPort object but when I published and run this code it is giving me an ArgumentException. This is the below exception,

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The object's type must be __ComObject or derived from __ComObject.
```

I found out that there is another way is to implement an IDisposable interface but how can I implement this interface in my form class which is already implemented by visual studio in the Form1.Designer.vb file. The code give by visual studio is given below,

```
    'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Any help in this regard would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, it is not at all obvious how you know that it "reopens itself".  Nevertheless, it is always wrong to call SerialPort.Close() and then call Open() again.  The MSDN docs specifically warn about this.  There is a worker thread (generates DataReceived event etc) that needs to exit before the port becomes available.  How long that takes is unpredictable, something very wrong if it takes a minute.  Perhaps you exaggerated a bit.  There is also excessively few benefits to allowing another app to steal the port.  Only sane thing to do is to *never* call Close.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, I read the MSDN document, therefore I am reopen the COM port by making a delay of 1-sec in this above code snippet. I even tries by making the delay to 5 or even to 10 seconds but not worked for me. I am actually using BeginInvoke in DataReceived Event and because I have used 5-10 sec of delay for reopen the COM port, I am sure this event will exit itself before I can reopen the COM port. But is there any way to make sure that this event exit itself before doing something ?